# NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.WidgetBuilder: method <init>()V not found when using org.primefaces 10.0.0

Tags: primefaces, weblogic12c

I'm working on a web JSF project with a WebLogic Server 12. I have tried to include org.primefaces, but I'm having this error when I'm accessing the web page from my web browser :

```
    ]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.WidgetBuilder: method <init>()V not found
    at org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.<init>(DefaultRequestContext.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhaseListener.afterPhase(RestoreViewPhaseListener.java:30)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Here is a sample from my `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
    
    
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.20</version>
                  <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                 
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.20</version>
                  <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>       
    
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomahawk12</artifactId>
                  <version>1.1.9</version>
                  <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                 
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomahawk-sandbox12</artifactId>
                  <version>1.1.9</version>
                  <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.prime.facestrace</groupId>
                    <artifactId>facestrace</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
    
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javaee</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                    <version>5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                    <version>10.0.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

And from my `web.xml` :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately I could not find any relevant information on Google. Maybe I'm missing something from the Weblogic Server configuration ?

Comment: Try removing `com.prime.facestrace`.

Comment: I really think you have something else going on. This class in your stack trace `org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext` does not even exist in PrimeFaces 10.0.0. So how can it be complaining about a class that does not exist in the PF 10.0.0 JAR. Are you sure you properly removed FacesTrace which is ancient?

Comment: Yes indeed, I had noticed that the `org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext` does not exist but I can't figure out why it's referencing it. I have removed the FacesTrace dependency from the `pom.xml` and I checked that it had been removed from the dependencies (which is the case)

Comment: OK then crack open your EAR file.  You have some old PrimeFaces JAR or something coming in.  I thought it was that FacesTrace and still suspect you have it being included?

Comment: I have checked the .ear file and there is not FacesTrace jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder (but Primefaces 10.0.0 is present and only this version).

Comment: OK then your error makes absolutely no sense. That class does not even exist.

Comment: Then I'll keep looking for a solution and post it if I find something. Thanks you anyway.

Comment: Great let us know what you find out.